# Pivot Customer Policies data

Tags: sql-server

Write a query to create a pivot table to display the  number of customers taken policies with policy_value 250000,75000,45000. Specify the name of the first column in the pivot table as  'customer_count' with literal value  as customerCount. Use: PIVOT

[image]

As a solution I have used the following code.

```
select id as customer_count, [250000], [75000], [45000]
from 
(
select * from customer_policy
)
PIVOT
(count(id) FOR policy_value IN [250000], [75000], [45000])
GO
```

But getting error as **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PIVOT'.**

***EDIT***
Output is required in the below format
[image]

Answer (score 3):

These are typographical error really. You have several errors in the above SQL.

1. You don't alias your subquery
2. You are missing parenthesis (`()`) around your `IN` clause
3. You don't alias your pivot
4. `ID` doesn't exist in the returned columns for your pivot, so needs to be removed

If you fix this, you get a valid query:

```sql
SELECT [250000],
       [75000],
       [45000]
FROM (SELECT * FROM customer_policy) cp
PIVOT (COUNT(id)
       FOR policy_value IN ([250000], [75000], [45000])) p;
```

Though, in true, you don't actually need the subquery:

```sql
SELECT [250000],
       [75000],
       [45000]
FROM customer_policy cp
    PIVOT (COUNT(id)
           FOR policy_value IN ([250000], [75000], [45000])) p;
```

You may need other columns in your `SELECT`, as you use a `*`, I don't know what other columns you want to expose.

Comment: output required as per the edit section.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by the "edit section" @ArijitBiswas .

Comment: I included an edit section in my question.

Comment: That's just a string literal, @ArijitBiswas . You can easily add a column with that into the `SELECT`.

Comment: Right now I am using the following query..

`SELECT 
    [250000],
    [75000],
    [45000]
FROM (SELECT id, policy_value FROM customer_policy) cp
PIVOT (COUNT(id) 
        FOR policy_value IN ([250000], [75000], [45000])) p;`
How to add the first column in the pivot table as 'customer_count' with literal value as customerCount.

Comment: `SELECT 'customer_count' AS customer_count, ...` @ArijitBiswas ... How to add a literal string value to a dataset is is basic of basics.

Answer (score -2):

Below is the answer to the question

```
SELECT 'customerCount' AS customer_count,
    [250000],
    [75000],
    [45000]
FROM (SELECT id, policy_value FROM customer_policy) cp
PIVOT (COUNT(id) 
        FOR policy_value IN ([250000], [75000], [45000])) p;
```

Comment: I fail to see how this is different to the answer I posted.

Comment: Nothing different from your answer. Your answer was missing the customerCount literals. I included this one here and posted the complete answer.

Comment: @ArijitBiswas you shouldn't directly copy other answers. Adding `'customerCount' AS customer_count` does not add any value and without that, this makes it a direct copy of Larnu's answer but this has much less detail