# Why is it showing Incorrect syntax error while using Pivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Write a query to create a pivot table to display the  number of address  in each city named 'Bangalore', 'Chennai' and 'Thane'. Specify the name of the first column in the pivot table as  'address_count' with literal value  as 'addressCount'. Use: PIVOT

[image]

As a solution I used the following code.

```
SELECT 'addressCount' AS address_count,
        'Bangalore',
        'Chennai',
        'Thane'
FROM (SELECT id, city FROM address) a
PIVOT (COUNT(id) 
        FOR city IN ('Bangalore', 'Chennai', 'Thane')) p;
```

Error message is displayed as ...

> Incorrect syntax near 'Bangalore'.

Comment: You are using literal strings for your object names... Look at the answer you got to your similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73884426/pivot-customer-policies-data) the other day.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu.. it worked.. Final code
`SELECT 'addressCount' AS address_count,
        [Bangalore],
        [Chennai],
        [Thane]
FROM (SELECT id, city FROM address) a
PIVOT (COUNT(id) 
        FOR city IN ([Bangalore], [Chennai], [Thane])) p;
`

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax is a bit faulty. Check out the following:

```
DECLARE @address TABLE(
id int, city nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @address VALUES (1, 'Bangalore'), (2, 'Bangalore'), (3, 'Bangalore'), (4, 'Bangalore'), 
                            (11, 'Chennai'), (12, 'Chennai'),
                            (21, 'Thane'),
                            (31, 'UNKNOWN')


SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id, city FROM @address) a
PIVOT (COUNT(id) 
        FOR city IN ([Bangalore], [Chennai], [Thane])) p;
```